# Excel and python using xlsxwriter - ignoring blanks when reading data but blank lines are being wrote to new excel file anyways

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, xlsxwriter

**Edited Question for clarification and proper formatting**

**The Problem**
I am using `xlrd` to parse some information from an excel sheet. I use `xlrd` to loop through the excel sheet. When a cell in the row matches a date I have predefined, information is pulled from the sheet and stored in a dictionary called `dataTickets()`. This is a nested dictionary.

```
params = '2015-53'
ticketData = {}
num=1

for row in range(sheetNUG.nrows):
    for col in range(sheetNUG.ncols / 76):
        if params in sheetNUG.cell_value(row, 56):
            if sheetNUG.cell_value(row, col):
                #print sheetNUG.cell_value(row, 59), sheetNUG.cell_value(row, 32), sheetNUG.cell_value(row, 56) #APPLICATION GROUP | APPLICATION | Params
                group = sheetNUG.cell_value(row, 59)
                application = sheetNUG.cell_value(row, 32)

                ticketData.setdefault(group, {})
                ticketData[group].setdefault(application, {'#':0})

                ticketData[group][application]['#'] += int(num)
                print "MATCH", row
        else:
            print row, "No Match"
```

I know it is ignoring empty rows/cells during reading as the original excel file is 27000 thousand lines (with 7000 empty). The `row` variable above never goes above 20000.

The problem is when I go to write the structure to an excel file:

```
for key in ticketData.keys():
    if key in ticketData:
        #print "\nKEY: ", key
        newsheet.write(row, col,    key)
        for item in ticketData[key]:
            newsheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
            #print "ITEM: ", item
            for num in ticketData[key][item]:
                #print "NUM: ", ticketData[key][item][num]
                newsheet.write(row, col + 2, ticketData[key][item][num])
            row += 1
    else:
        print "EMPTY!"
newbook.close()
```

This prints to file perfectly except there are about 7000 lines printed first, then the data structure.

**Extra info**
I've linked the entire code here: http://pastebin.com/1McTPScU just in case anybody in the future wants to see the full code.
And here's some pictures of the end result just in case you are still unclear as to what the issue is: https://gyazo.com/b0fca13ccf45b15a82b7b1ce2b9fb1c9 & https://gyazo.com/d4ed4d1f287baea23750afad408d4c7f

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi there thanks for your reply and for pointing out the flaws in my question.  It's late here at the moment but I'll edit my question as soon as I get to my PC tomorrow morning!

Comment: Ok edited there following the guides you linked. 

I left the links at the very bottom as I feel it could be useful in case anybody is still unclear. I explained the problem in detail in the main question though!